# Rule to set spacing on import statements with eslint?

Tags: import, eslint, space

In my code I have things like this:

```
import  Something from './Something';
```

And I would like to normalize it to this:

```
import Something from './Something';
```

However, my keyword-spacing rule, although it applies to everything else, doesn't seem to apply to import statements:

```
'keyword-spacing': ['error', { 'before': true, 'after': true }],
```

Do I need to use a different rule for this and, if so, which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use ESLint rule [no-multi-spaces](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-spaces) for the spacing.

```
"no-multi-spaces": ["error"]
```